# How to group overlying objects in JavaScript + Canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

Please, I need some help!
Ok, there is HTML5 document with canvas. Javascript renders map on canvas.
On the map there are trackers which show location of cars in city. Each tracker - it's the icon with text label, containing number.

There might be situation when cars placed really close to each other, in this case icon of one tracker might overly label of another. It's normal that there is overlying icons, but the labels should be always in sight.

I need an algorythm of grouping labels of overlying trackers. Please help! I don't even know where to start!

PS: This should be done without any third-party libraries exept jQuery and jQuery UI (requirement of the customer).

Comment: _“I don't even know where to start!”_ – by paying attention in Math classes …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never have done this, but here is my idea about this:

Let's say you have an array of three cars like this:

```
var cars=[{name:"car1",x:100,y:101},{name:"car2",x:99,y:101},{name:"car3",x:90,y:111}];
```

I would first sort it by the position:

```
cars.sort(sortfunction)

function sortfunction(a, b){
   return a.x - b.x + a.y - b.y
}
```

When you then place the cars on the map, have a look at the previous position. If it's near, add a label class:

```
var label=0;
for(var i=0; i<cars.length; i++) {
  if(i>=1) {
    if(Math.abs(cars[i-1].x-cars[i].x+cars[i-1].y-cars[i].y)<10) {
      //Add your element with a label class $("<div class='car label"+label+"' style='...'>")
       console.log(cars[i-1].name+" is to near to "+cars[i].name);
      label++;
    }
    else {
      //Add your element normal $("<div class='car' style='...'>")
       label=0;   
    }
  }
}
```

your label classes should position the label-element:

```
.label0 {
    /* position north */
}
.label1 {
    /* position west*/
}
.label2 {
    /* position east*/
}
/* can go on with nw, ne, se and sw if needed*/
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfaLr/2/) which shows this approach.